# Error trying to programmatically add a controller file to a navigation controller without creating storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to push a view controller onto a navigation controller without designing a storyboard. Is this possible as I am new to Swift? I created my navigation controller in appdelegate.swift file:

```
let viewController: UIViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let navController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)


self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
self.window?.rootViewController = navController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And now in ViewController.swift file, when the user clicks the button below is the file when I try to add the signInController:

```
func SignIn(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Im, here")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signInController") as! signInController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Below is my ***Error:***

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x608000269600>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'signInController''

**Question:**
Do I have to create a storyboard and go to the inspector Id to add the storyboard Id? But what if I wanted to accomplish this without creating a storyboard file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a storyboard then you shouldn't attempt to create your sign-in view controller from a storyboard. Change the code to create the view controller directly:

```
func SignIn(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("I'm, here")
    let controller = signInController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

BTW - you need to rename everything to follow standard naming conventions. Classnames should start with uppercase letters. All method, variable, and parameters names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: @maddy thanks a lot. Do you recommend using storyboards or not for developing a project?

Comment: That's up to you. I've never used them in 8 years of iOS development. I prefer code but most people don't.

Comment: Ok. Is it just preference. I am very new to IOS but want to learn without storyboard? If i dont use storyboard do i have to use XIB/NIBs

Comment: No. You can do everything in code. That's what I do. I don't have a single xib/nib or storyboard (except the required launch screen) in my very large and complex app. Every view controller and screen is 100% code.

Comment: it may seem challenging in doing all in code but i'm thinking i will learn a lot

Comment: I like to do everything in code because then I know exactly what is happening. There's no "magic" happening behind the scenes. BTW -  Please don't forget to up vote and/or accept helpful answers. Accepting an answer indicates the best answer that solves your issue. It seems you haven't accepted an answer for any of your questions in quite some time.

Comment: im sorry i just accepted your answer and thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well you want to create a viewController without using the storyboard and you're still trying to use the storyboard in your code.

Try something like this instead:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let myViewController: YourNewViewController = YourNewViewController()
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController!)
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks. Is it better to develop with Storyboards or without?

Comment: I prefer storyboard. 1: You get a better overview of your entire project view. 2: You get a lot for "free". 3: It´s a lot easier to handle the constraints for your elements. This is my opinion, if you need any help with the storyboard I´ll be glad to help out @user3497437

Comment: thanks will do. Will try to do an overview in storyboard but will try to develop in all code. I know it will be alot of work but might get a good understanding